# AS3: How do IDEs extract class inheritance info?

Tags: ide, actionscript-3

I'm wondering what the simplest way would be to get -- *in my own custom code* -- a complete AS3 inheritance tree and inherited members for every class:

- Search catalog.xml for each SWC, then find each appropriate class file listed in the catalog, and parse it?
- Or some other, much simpler way?

In other words, I require full awareness of the AS3 inheritance chain (all core and custom classes), including public and protected members belonging to superclasses which may appear in subclasses. This info is to be plugged into a language converter I am writing (AS3->some other language).

I'm wondering how eg. FlashDevelop or FlashBuilder (Eclipse) does this. I've had a look at the catalog.xml file that appears in each .SWC, but while this provides some insight into the inheritance chain, it gives no indication of how IDEs extract information like inherited members used in autocompletion.

Where should this information be pulled from? ...Bearing in mind FD (for instance) is written in C# and so `describeType` probably isn't an option.

Comment: FlashDevelop has `Library` folder which contains `playerglobal.swc`, it's likely there is a catalog with dependencies.

Comment: @weltraumpirat I am looking, but fail to see how this can help me... Can you explain?

Comment: @weltraumpirat Correct, this is the most central issue and I'm currently looking into it. Apparently [swfutils](http://segfaultlabs.com/swfutils) does this reliably, but I am not sure whether it is still available for download (SVN checkout not working from the given URL).

Comment: @weltraumpirat "If I'm working in AS3" (which, yes, I am), and I were willing to load in the SWCs being evaluated, I could call `describeType()` on each class in the catalog, no? I would have to load every SWC, but then the core libraries (in playerglobal.swc) are only 130kb...

Comment: @weltraumpirat Thanks for the info. I just can't see myself needing any more reflection info than that which `describeType()` already provides. P.S. Perhaps you can put your various comments into an answer. At least, you've helped me to know I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the full dependency graph, including private and internal APIs, you will have to use bytecode introspection - parsing class (text) files will not yield any information on imported classes from .SWC libraries.  Have a look at the [AVM2 specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf) for more info on ActionScript bytecode.

If you're going to be working in AS3, you can access type information for any class at runtime, using [`describeType()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html).  However, its scope is limited (only public members are included), and it is heavy on performance, so you will have to implement some kind of caching mechanism, and perhaps tweak your XML parsing, too.

If you want to save yourself the trouble, check out [as3commons-reflect](http://as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/index.html).  It provides all of the above, along with a very convenient API.  Anytime you're using reflections on more than the odd rare occasion, I highly recommend it - you'll save yourself a lot of time and energy writing what others have already written ;).

Also, if you need access to private and internal members, or if you want to manipulate classes at runtime, there's [as3commons-bytecode](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/index.html), which works on the actual bytecode of loaded classes, and allows for all kinds of voodoo and dark magic.

Comment: New day, same issues :) I have one last question I was hoping you could clarify for me. Do you know whether the as3commons-bytecode loads the SWF as a ByteArray and works on it from there, rather than attempting load it using a Loader instance (thus making the SWF runtime accessible)? Because I'm currently getting `VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code` when trying to load a different version of the SWF inside playerglobal.swc, to reflect on. Just off the top of your head.

Comment: It's loaded via Loader.  But you won't have to load the standalone playerglobal.swc - it should be embedded in whatever program you are trying to analyze.  I really don't know about different target player versions coexisting at the same time - if it is at all possible, you'll probably have to experiment with application domain settings.

Answer (score 0):

I really wish to avoid a link to a software but this one just seems to be what you are looking for.

[AS3 Class Diagram Viewer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Home-Education/AS3-Class-Diagram-Viewer.shtml)

[image]

Besides that, the documentation always seemed very well organized to see the class hierarchy.

You could also get an offline version... [where can I download AS3 flash platform full documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178740/where-can-i-download-as3-flash-platform-full-documentation)

Comment: Hi and thanks; I see some misunderstanding based on my original question and have changed it to be more accurate, although clearly the title of the question doesn't match your answer. I don't need a view in the visual sense -- I need a data structure representing the class hierarchy, which I can work with.